# Is there a way to click windows fileshare links in macos?

Tags: macos, network, smb

My company (like many others) primarily uses Windows computers and as such has a lot of Windows-based fileshares. We have also standardized which fileshares map to which lettered drives on those PCs, so everyone has the same "F" drive.

I know that I can use the "connect to server" functionality using the smb: protocol to connect to them. However, a lot of our intranet websites and emails have links that just point to "F:/docs/some/files". When I am using my mac I can't click on those links because Macos doesn't know how to handle them.

Is there some way to configure Macos, or some app I can install, which will automatically handle those links and map them to the appropriate smb: path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make Windows-style SMB share paths launch correctly?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22831/is-there-a-way-to-make-windows-style-smb-share-paths-launch-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

There is a wonderful free tool called WinShortcutter for Mac that allows you to do exactly what you're wanting.

Winshortcutter can be found here: http://winshortcutter.com/

After installing, you can change a setting in the Mac services screen to allow this as a right click option as well.